# Problem in building Gradle in Android Studio

Tags: android, gradle, build.gradle, vpn

I almost have this problem in most projects that when I want to bring an existing project to Android, I always encounter such problems. What should I do to solve the problem permanently?

Google has disabled this part for Iranians, and if I want to import any project in Android Studio beforehand, I have to connect to a [VPN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_private_network) that can import the used libraries. Is there a way to do it without connecting to a VPN, Downloaded the libraries?

Can I manually download all the libraries in one folder and then put all the URLs in the project because it's hard to connect to the VPN and if it does the speed is super slow.

Or is there another address that can be changed in Android Studio settings, like [NuGet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NuGet) in Visual Studio where you can change the address of receiving libraries and download libraries from that address?

#### Error text

```
 Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
    Could not find gradle-4.2.2.jar (com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.2).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/4.2.2/gradle-4.2.2.jar
    Could not find builder-4.2.2.jar (com.android.tools.build:builder:4.2.2).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/builder/4.2.2/builder-4.2.2.jar
    Could not find aaptcompiler-4.2.2.jar (com.android.tools.build:aaptcompiler:4.2.2).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/aaptcompiler/4.2.2/aaptcompiler-4.2.2.jar
    Could not find bundletool-1.1.0.jar (com.android.tools.build:bundletool:1.1.0).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/bundletool/1.1.0/bundletool-1.1.0.jar
    Could not find sdk-common-27.2.2.jar (com.android.tools:sdk-common:27.2.2).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/sdk-common/27.2.2/sdk-common-27.2.2.jar
    Could not find sdklib-27.2.2.jar (com.android.tools:sdklib:27.2.2).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/sdklib/27.2.2/sdklib-27.2.2.jar
    Could not find common-27.2.2.jar (com.android.tools:common:27.2.2).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/common/27.2.2/common-27.2.2.jar
    Could not find protos-27.2.2.jar (com.android.tools.analytics-library:protos:27.2.2).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/analytics-library/protos/27.2.2/protos-27.2.2.jar
    Could not find core-proto-0.0.8-alpha01.jar (com.google.testing.platform:core-proto:0.0.8-alpha01).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/testing/platform/core-proto/0.0.8-alpha01/core-proto-0.0.8-alpha01.jar
    Could not find zipflinger-4.2.2.jar (com.android:zipflinger:4.2.2).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/zipflinger/4.2.2/zipflinger-4.2.2.jar
    Could not find apksig-4.2.2.jar (com.android.tools.build:apksig:4.2.2).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/apksig/4.2.2/apksig-4.2.2.jar
```

#### *[build.gradle](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/tutorial_using_tasks.html)* file

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.2"
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter() // Warning: this repository is going to shut down soon
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

[image]

Comment: You seem to have network problems (or the server was temporary not available) because the first jar `https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/4.2.2/gradle-4.2.2.jar` can be downloaded without any problems. If gradle has cached these "file not available info" you can delete you gradle cache `~/.gradle` in your home directory.

Comment: If I can download the file from the URL, how should I read the address of the desired file from the folder inside the project itself, such as Visual Stadio, which downloads the desired library and files once? and always reads from the same downloaded files.
Updated post. @Robert

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand your comment. As I wrote Gradle caches all downloads in the `.gradle` folder in your home dir. Simply delete that folder and its's content and retry. If it still nor work check your network configuration.

Comment: I mean, if I download the **gradle-4.2.2.jar** file from the desired address, how can I make it read from the folder that I introduce to get this file, and is such a thing possible or not? @Robert

Comment: Don't try to download Gradle or other dependencies manually. While Gradle performs bootstrapping and building a project it download about 200-500 files - you don't want to download them all manually. Simply fix the network problems on your PC or the internet connection (e.g. defect proxy settings, VPN usage, wrong date/time ...).

Comment: This is a problem for banning google if there is a problem with the internet how can i post here. @Robert

Comment: These problems happen every series in Android projects, that's why I want a solution to be able to manually download the libraries and put them in a folder and then take the libraries from there forever. @Robert

Comment: Currently, I can't open https://developer.google.com address, so I put vpn in one of the tags in the question. That's why I asked here whether there is another solution other than vpn or not.@Robert

Comment: Gradle need Internet access at least once per project to download all necessary files. BTW: Just adding a VPN tag doesn't explain anything. If you have a question formulate it accordingly, describe your problem its possible cause and what you tried. At it's current state nobody is able to understand what you are asking for.

Comment: I edited my question and gave the explanation in the second paragraph, and I also put the image of the inactive page in the question, is the explanation clear? @Robert

Comment: You already give the answer: you are blocked because your internet connection is locate din Iran. That block is on server side and most likely based on your IP and the only way to get around is a VPN.

Comment: Please [provide](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76296378/edit) the error message [as text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/). (But *** *** *** *** *** ***[without](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/131011)*** *** *** *** *** *** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the question should appear as if it was written today.) Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by a forbidden HTTP error (403). You would need a VPN or a proxy to bypass it.

I recommend using an HTTP proxy as both Gradle and Android Studio support it, and it doesn't need complex configuration to get it to work.

There is a guide for setting an HTTP proxy for Android Studio [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/studio-config#setup-proxy).

Usually, after configuring proxy settings, Gradle would ask if you want to use the same proxy configurations for Gradle too.

Otherwise, if Gradle doesn't prompt, you should do it manually. Add these lines in your global *gradle.properties* file:

`systemProp.http.proxyHost=[proxy host]`

`systemProp.http.proxyPort=[proxy port]`

Comment: The link you provided is not working

Comment: Sorry about that. I fixed the link.

Comment: Was this generated by [ChatGPT](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-chatgpt-is-banned) (or similar)? (Not a rhetorical question.)

Comment: @PeterMortensen No, it wasn't. Just wanted to help since I had the same issue and know it's not fun seeing 403 errors from Google. I'm curious though, what made you think this was generated by GPT? Are there mistakes in the answer?

Answer (score -1):

In my opinion, the only and necessary solution for you is to use VPN changer software. You can buy some VPN changer software to completely fix the problems.